# How do you set up this constraint in integer programming using binary variables?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

> Mike wants to invest in $X_1$ if and only if he invests into $X_2$ or
>   $X_3$ or both.

Please help i can't get my head around this

Thanks

Comment: Something like $X_1\geq \frac12\left(X_2+X_3 \right), \ \ X_1,X_2,X_3\in\{0,1\}$. But additional the objective function has to be known.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint
$$ X_1 \geq \frac12 (X_2 + X_3) $$
would ensure that $X_1$ is one if either is one. On the other hand:
$$ X_1 \leq X_2 + X_3 $$
would ensure that $X_1$ is zero if both are zero.

Comment: In your second inequality $\frac{1}{2}$ can be removed. There is also a typo ($X_1$ on the right hand side should be $X_3$)